# Boost::Asio stand-alone std::thread in QT GUI crashes when closing

Tags: c++, qt, asynchronous, boost, boost-asio

I have a QT widget application that contains a boost::asio `udp` client class `RTPClient` running in a stand alone `std::thread`.

The RTP client uses a boost `deadline_timer` and a boost `socket` running in a separate stand alone `std::thread` (not the QT main thread) to continually transmit udp data to a server listening on an `IP address:port` specified in the GUI.  The asio calls are all asynchronous and are kicked off from the main QT thread via the `on_start_clicked` qt slot attached to the start button.  This is where mpRTPClient->asyncIOThreadFn() is invoked; starting the chain of asio callbacks (which run in the asio thread (not the main QT gui thread).  The slot that kicks things off is shown below:

```
void MainWindow::on_start_clicked(bool flag)
{
    // launch protocol thread
    if (!flag) {
        // temporarily disable the start/stop button
        //ui->start->setEnabled(false);
        // must call reset in order to process the
        // callback handlers run(), poll() etc.
        mpIOService->reset();
        // keep RTPClient busy while waiting for network IO
        mpWork = std::make_shared<io_service::work>(*mpIOService);
        const auto targetIP = ui->targetIP->text().
            split(":").at(0).toStdString();
        const auto targetPort = static_cast<uint16_t>(std::stoi(
            ui->targetIP->text().split(":").at(1).toStdString()));
        mpRTPClient = std::make_unique<RTPClient>(
            RTPClient::RTPConfig{ targetIP, targetPort }, 
            mIPCQueue, mpIOService);
        if (mpRTPClient) {
            // kick off the asynchronous boost asio operations
            mpRTPClient->asyncIOThreadFn();
        }
        mpAsioThread = std::make_unique<std::thread>(
            [this]() { mpIOService->run(); });
    } else {
    }
}
```

The stack at the time of closing is as follows:

```
    ucrtbased.dll!00007ff949cc3b85()    Unknown
    ucrtbased.dll!00007ff949cc0713()    Unknown
>   afdx.exe!boost::alignment::aligned_free(void * ptr) Line 29 C++
    afdx.exe!boost::asio::aligned_delete(void * ptr) Line 133   C++
    afdx.exe!boost::asio::detail::thread_info_base::~thread_info_base() Line 117    C++
    [External Code] 
    afdx.exe!boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_io_context::run(boost::system::error_code & ec) Line 207 C++
    afdx.exe!boost::asio::io_context::run() Line 63 C++
    afdx.exe!MainWindow::on_start_clicked::__l5::<lambda_1>::operator()() Line 300  C++
    [External Code]
```

Whenever I close the application, it crashes in the std::thread `join()` call (which is called via the MainWindow's destructor - I have no idea why this is happening.  It destructs fine if I do not kick off any asio requests so I presume it has something do with some outstanding work objects in the `IOService`.

The cleanup code which is called from the destructor terminates the work sentinel and also shuts down the socket.

The QT MainWindow class is pretty straight forward containing a number of smart pointers.

```
QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE
class RTPClient;

class MainWindow final : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow() override;

private slots:
    void on_start_clicked(bool checked);
private:
    void stopSubSystems();

    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_service> mpIOService;
    std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work> mpWork;
    std::unique_ptr<std::thread> mpAsioThread;
    std::unique_ptr<RTPClient> mpRTPClient;

    //! Future associated with the std::async worker thead
    //! for performing long running background tasks
    //! (initialize/un-initialize). Set as member instead of
    //! temporary, because std::future<void> going out of temp
    //! scope would block waiting for the underlying thread
    //! to complete (which is not what we want).
    std::future<void> mFuture;
};
```

The destructor code that is supposed to terminate outstanding IO operations and wait for the mpAsioThread to terminate via `join()` is as follows:

```
//! Destructor
MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
    try {
        // reset the work object - no more work
        stopAsioThread();
    } catch (const std::exception&) {
    }
}

void
MainWindow::stopAsioThread()
{
    // make sure that we have no more work keeping services alive
    // check to see if the protocol threads were started
    if (mpRTPClient) {
        // Initiate the shutdown procedure - closing the IPC queue
        // followed by canceling any socket operations
        mpRTPClient->shutdown();

        // reset work sentinel to allow the pool to finish
        mpWork.reset();

        mpAsioThread->join();

        // now that the threads have terminated, stop the IOService
        mpIOService->stop();

        // call the destructor on the VCDUProtocol here
        mpRTPClient.reset();
    }
}
```

The UDP client class is as follows:

```
class RTPClient final
{
public:
    struct RTPConfig {
        /**
         * Config.
         *
         * @param aHostName
         *               [in] Target host name/IP address.
         * @param rPortNum
         *               [in] UDP port number to send to.
         */
        constexpr explicit RTPConfig(
            std::string aHostName,
            const uint16_t& rPortNum)
            : mHostName(aHostName)
            , mPortNum(rPortNum)
        {}
        std::string mHostName;
        uint16_t mPortNum;
    };

    explicit RTPClient(RTPConfig aConfig,
        std::shared_ptr<IPCQueue<std::vector<uint8_t>>>& ipcQueue,
        std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_service> pIOService)
        : mConfig{ aConfig }
        , mIPCQueue{ ipcQueue }
        , mpIOService{ std::move(pIOService) }
        , mpSocket{}
        , mpSocketTimer{}
        , mpEndpoint{}
        , mpAudioData{}
        , mShutdownFlag{ false }
    {}

    //! Defaulted destructor.
    ~RTPClient() = default;

    //! Deleted copy constructor.
    RTPClient(const RTPClient&) = delete;

    //! Deleted move constructor.
    RTPClient(RTPClient&&) = delete;

    //! Deleted move assignment.
    RTPClient& operator=(RTPClient&&) = delete;

    //! Deleted copy assignment.
    RTPClient& operator=(RTPClient) = delete;

    /**
     * Thread function to initiate asynchronous operations.
     *
     * <p>Asynchronously kicks off the async operations.
     */
    void asyncIOThreadFn();
    
    /**
     * Shutdown the protocol instance by shutting down the IPC
     * queue and closing the socket and associated timers etc.
     *
     * <p>This is achieved by setting a flag which is read by the
     * busy loop as an exit condition.
     */
    void shutdown();
protected:
    void handle_send_to(const boost::system::error_code& error/*, size_t bytes_sent*/);

    void handle_timeout(const boost::system::error_code& error);

    /**
     * Close the open socket and cancel the associated timer.
     *
     * @param ec     [out] Boost error code.
     */
    void closeSocketResources(boost::system::error_code& ec);
private:
    //! Settings.
    RTPConfig mConfig;
    //! Thread safe queue.
    std::shared_ptr<IPCQueue<std::vector<uint8_t>>> mIPCQueue;
    //! The boost asio IO Service object for TCP & Timer services.
    std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_service> mpIOService;
    std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::ip::udp::socket> mpSocket;
    std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::deadline_timer> mpSocketTimer;
    std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint> mpEndpoint;
    std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]> mpAudioData;
    //! Thread atomic shutdown flag.
    std::atomic<bool> mShutdownFlag;
    //! Singleton and critical support.
    static std::mutex gMutexGuard;
};
```

and the implementation of the RTPClient class

```
void
RTPClient::handle_send_to(const error_code& error/*, size_t bytes_sent*/) {
    if (!error && !mShutdownFlag) {
        mpSocketTimer->expires_from_now(
            boost::posix_time::seconds(1));
        mpSocketTimer->async_wait(boost::bind(
            &RTPClient::handle_timeout, 
            this, _1));
    }
}

void
RTPClient::handle_timeout(const error_code& error) {
    if (!error && !mShutdownFlag) {
        mpSocket->async_send_to(
            buffer("sent after timeout"), *mpEndpoint,
            boost::bind(&RTPClient::handle_send_to, this, _1));
    }
}

void
RTPClient::asyncIOThreadFn()
{
    mpEndpoint = std::make_unique<ip::udp::endpoint>(
        ip::address::from_string(mConfig.mHostName), 
        mConfig.mPortNum);
    mpSocket = std::make_unique<ip::udp::socket>(
        *mpIOService, mpEndpoint->protocol());
    mpSocketTimer = std::make_unique<deadline_timer>(
        *mpIOService);
    // kick off the async chain
    mpSocket->async_send_to(
        buffer("this is a test"), 
        *mpEndpoint, boost::bind(
            &RTPClient::handle_send_to, 
            this, _1));
}

/**
 * Shutdown the protocol instance by shutting down the IPC
 * queue and closing the socket and associated timers etc.
 *
 * <p>This is achieved by setting a flag which is read by the
 * busy loop as an exit condition.
 */
void
RTPClient::shutdown()
{
    // set the shared shutdown flag
    mShutdownFlag = true;

    // wake up any locked threads so they can see the above flag
    if (mIPCQueue) {
        mIPCQueue->shutdown();
    }
    error_code ignoredError;
    closeSocketResources(ignoredError);
}

/**
 * Close the open socket and cancel the associated timer.
 *
 * @param ec     [out] Boost error code.
 */
void
RTPClient::closeSocketResources(error_code& ec)
{
    // stop the socket timer - do not reset it
    // as there are some time sensitive parts in the code
    // where mpSocketTimer is dereferenced
    if (mpSocketTimer) {
        mpSocketTimer->cancel();
    }

    // close the socket if we created & opened it, making
    // sure that we close down both ends of the socket.
    if (mpSocket && mpSocket->is_open()) {
        mpSocket->shutdown(ip::udp::socket::shutdown_both, ec);
        // reset so we will reallocate and then reopen
        // via boost::async_connect(...) later.
        mpSocket.reset();
    }
}
```

Comment: `shutdown()` is now called by the Qt thread, I can't find in the docs that it is safe, you can call it from the `std::thread` by using: `mpIOService->post([this](){ mpRTPClient->shutdown(); });`

Comment: @Reinder It would not be threadsafe (only execution contexts and strand are documented as such). However, you are looking in the wrong place for documentation, as `RTPClient` is not an Asio entity, and the definition of `RTPClient::shutdown` is not shown in the question. A reasonable guess is that it sets `mShutdownFlag` making it threadsafe.

Comment: @sehe you are correct - (it sets an atomic shutdown flag and calls a private fn to close the socket resources (canceling the socket timer and closing any open sockets via the shutdown_both method). I think I should edit the question with the shutdown implementation - it would make the question clearer.

Comment: `closeSocketResources` looks like it's not properly thread-synchronized. No idea about IPCQueue obviously